# Android Studio, Grade: please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them

Tags: android, gradle, android-proguard

How to use -dontwarn? or -ignorewarnings?
Where to put them?

Can someone give example how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your proguard-rules.pro file, you can specify the flags -dontwarn and -ignorewarnings

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
```

I have added this into my proguard-rules file. It means that if there is an unresolved reference for this particular glob pattern or if there's some warnings generated for this, do not warn me.

You specify -ignorewarnings similarly

Have a look at the official docs for further details
[Proguard Usage Manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-dontwarn` in your `proguard-rules.pro` file in your app module.
For example:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v4**
```

More info [here](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage).

Also you can run:

```
./gradlew :app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForUatDebug --debug
```

to get more details.